# How do I fix the error: Cannot find module '__sveltekit/paths' in sveltekit when migrating to 1.7.2?

Tags: runtime-error, sveltekit

I was migrating to sveltekit 1.7.2 from 1.5.3, as there was a security vulnerability. NPM did not tell me that 1.7.2 was a breaking change, so I installed the new version. I found that the latest compatible version was 1.5.6, anything higher resulted in the same error. I don't know why this is an issue, I guess it wouldn't be if you were making a new project, but as I am not doing that, can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Entire error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '__sveltekit/paths' imported from [path to project]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js'
    at nodeImport (file:///[path to project]/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:52431:25)
    at ssrImport (file:///[path to project]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:52354:20)
    at eval (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:5:37)
    at async instantiateModule (file://path to project]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:52400:9)
```

This error tells me that the file "__sveltekit/paths" has either moved, been replaced, or deleted entirely. Does anyone know where the file is now/if it even still exists?

Please note, that I see this error in the browser and in the node console. No other content is rendered *at all*.

Comment: This doesn't feel sufficient for an answer, but I ran into this in my unit tests when upgrading and found a solution here: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8996
The problem for me was trying to import $app/environment. To narrow it down, you can try to comment out imports until you figure out which import specifically is causing this problem, and research from there.

Comment: That might help, thanks!